# `make V=99` not showing the compiler command

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

```
[il@vmarch openwrt]$ make V=99
...
make -C /home/il/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-ar71xx_generic/linux-3.10.36 HOSTCFLAGS="-O2 -I/home/il/openwrt/staging_dir/host/include -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes" CROSS_COMPILE="mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc-" ARCH="mips" KBUILD_HAVE_NLS=no CONFIG_SHELL="/usr/bin/bash" V='' CC="mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc" modules
make[5]: Entering directory '/home/il/openwrt/build_dir/target-mips_34kc_uClibc-0.9.33.2/linux-ar71xx_generic/linux-3.10.36'
...
  CC [M]  net/netfilter/xt_comment.o
net/netfilter/xt_comment.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant
 0 0
 ^
```

How to make it print `gcc ...` instead of `CC [M]`

Answer (score 3):

According to `make help`:

> `make V=0|1 [targets]` 0 => quiet build (default), 1 => verbose build
>
> `make V=2   [targets]` 2 => give reason for rebuild of target

No `V=99` anywhere... just use `V=1` to see the commands run.